# taxweb ransack_advanced_search won't... search

Tags: search, rubygems, ransack

I am using https://github.com/taxweb/ransack_advanced_search to search a table using condition groups. However, I can't seem to get this to work (yes, I am new to this!).

The set-up seems simple enough, and I followed the instructions to the letter, but the search simply results in all records being displayed (if indeed it occurs at all). Any help appreciated.

Controller:

```
class QuizzesController < ApplicationController
before_action :set_quiz, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

def index
@search = Quiz.search(params[:q])
@results = @search.result().includes(:category, :genre)

if params[:tag]
  @quizzes = Quiz.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
 @quizzes = Quiz.all
end

end

def new
 @quiz = Quiz.new
end

def create
 @quiz = Quiz.new(quiz_params)

if @quiz.save
        redirect_to quizzes_path
    else
        render "new"
end
end

def edit
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
end

def update
        if @quiz.update_attributes(quiz_params)
            redirect_to quizzes_path
        else
            render "edit"
        end
end

def show
  @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
end

def destroy
    @quiz.destroy
respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to quizzes_url, notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
end

end

private
  def set_quiz
    @quiz = Quiz.find(params[:id])
  end

def quiz_params
params.require(:quiz).permit(:genre, :title, :image, :tags, :Actions, :q, :tag_list, :name, :category, :category_id, :genre_id, :tag_me, :sample_text, :name)
end

end
```

Model:

```
class Quiz < ActiveRecord::Base

def self.ransackable_associations(*)
 %w( category genre )
end

def self.ransackable_attributes(*)
 %w( category title genre tag_me ) + _ransackers.keys
end

mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
belongs_to :category
belongs_to :genre
acts_as_taggable


validates :title, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }
validates :image, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }
validates :tag_me, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }
validates :sample_text, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }
validates :tag_list, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }
validates :category_id, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }
validates :genre_id, :presence => {:message => "Can't be blank." }

end
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
root "quizzes#index"    

get 'tags/:tag', to: 'quizzes#index', as: :tag


resources :quizzes do
  collection do
    match :advanced_search, to: 'quizzes#index', via: :post
  end
end


end
```

application.html.erb (head):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>QuizTags</title>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<!-- <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"> -->
<%= tinymce_assets %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= csrf_meta_tags %>
<%= yield(:ransack_advanced_search_setup) %>

etc.
```

index.html.erb:

```
<%= render partial: 'ransack_advanced_search/advanced_search',
locals: {
   search_url: advanced_search_quizzes_path, 
   redirect_path: quizzes_path 
}
%>
```

```html
<table id="quizzes" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-responsive">
 <thead>
    <tr>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Genre</th>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Tags</th>
    <th>Actions</th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
    <% @quizzes.each do |quiz| %>
    <tr>
    <td><%= quiz.category.name %></td>
    <td><%= quiz.genre.name %></td>
    <td><%= quiz.title %></td>
    <td><%= image_tag quiz.image_url(:thumb).to_s %></td>
    <td><%= quiz.tag_me %></td>
    <td><%= link_to "View", quiz %> <br> <%= link_to 'Edit', edit_quiz_path(quiz) 
    %> <br> <%= link_to 'Delete', quiz, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %> </td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
```

Many thanks - any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Change `@results` in your controller and change it to `@quizzes` and get rid of the if statement for now just to see if you can get it working correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this Chase. Didn't make a difference, unfortunately. The weird thing is there are no errors - the search just doesn't seem to be performed.